# MySQL Get list with values from two columns

Tags: mysql

Say I have this table with two columns. Both columns contain IP-addresses. I want a `SELECT`query that gets me a list of all ip-addresses that occur in either the first column, or the second column, or both. Just a list of all distinct ip-addresses in that table. How is that done? I would have thought that `SELECT DISTINCT ip_src, ip_dst FROM table` would have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your example only applies the distinct to ip_src. To get just one column try a UNION:

```
SELECT ip_src FROM table
UNION
SELECT ip_dst FROM table
```

As noted in the comments not only will the UNION remove duplicates between the columns but also those that occur with the columns meaning using a DISTINCT is unnecessary.

Comment: Nice. Did the trick. Will accept in 8 minutes, cause you were too fast for Stackoverflow :)

Comment: That's a hell of a long 8 minutes!

Comment: @EmileBergeron should I wait here too still. Welcome.

Comment: @EmileBergeron lol  It has definitely been a long 8 minutes.